# 3 nested for loops don't appear to be enumerating through the correct values

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void compute_it(int k, int n){
    for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            for(int z = 0; z < j; z++){
                if(i == 1 && j == 0){
                    cout << "in here\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    compute_it(2,3);
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. It's probably a really dumb error, but I don't understand why the "in here" is not being printed when I run this code.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop iterates on the condition `z < j`. In that case, `j` will never be 0 when that loop is running.